# Cfdocumentitem pagebreak during loop gives extra blank page before the data populated

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

I am using coldfuion 11 on Luix. I got extra blank pages before the data populated. It looks page break before. I have tried several ideas, researched the topics at stackoverflow, but couldn't solve the issue.  Here is my code:

```
<CFLOOP Query="details">


   <CFIF tracking_entry_type_code is "P">

      <cfset mode=details.currentrow mod 30>
      <CFIF CurrTrackingEntryDesc is not details.tracking_entry_desc>
        <tr>

          <th colspan="7" align="left">#details.tracking_entry_desc#</th>
        </tr>
        <CFSET CurrTrackingEntryDesc = details.tracking_entry_desc>
      </CFIF>        

     <tr >

        <td ><font size="2">#mode# #details.expense_desc#</td>
        <td><font size="2">#details.employee_id#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><font size="2">#details.payroll_title_code#</td>
        <td><font size="2">#details.payroll_dos_code#</font></td>
        <td align="left"><font size="2">#DateFormat( details.expense_date, "mm/dd/yy" )#</font></td>
        <td align="right"><font size="2">#details.account_charged#</font></td>                    
        <td align="right"><font size="2">#DecimalFormat( details.cost_shared_amount )#</td>
     </tr>

 </CFIF>
 <cfif mode eq 0 >
        <cfdocumentitem type="pagebreak">
       </cfdocumentitem>
     </cfif>  
</CFLOOP>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data set that you're looping over looks like, but from an outsider's perspective, it looks like the first record in the data has a "mode" of 0, and the "tracking_entry_type_code" is not "P".

To do some add'l debugging, try something like this inside of your CFLOOP tag :

```
<CFIF tracking_entry_type_code is "P">
    data here, 
    mode = #mode#, tracking_entry_type_code = #tracking_entry_type_code#
<cfelse>
    if something is here, it might cause a blank row, 
    mode = #mode#, tracking_entry_type_code = #tracking_entry_type_code#
</cfif>
```

and see if the first row of output has a mode of 0, which would cause a line break.

Hope this helps.